# Can anyone please help me with this ETAP Project?

Tags: power, load, system, electrical

I'm trying to run the load flow study, but instead I'm getting this error.

**Error 101-01: [Bus 2] Bus base kV is out of 40% range from bus nominal kV.
Error 722: [XFMR 1] 2W transformer secondary kV is out of 40% range from bus nominal kV.**

Here's the screenshot of my project:
[image]

I honestly don't know what's wrong, I'm literally doing everything as instructed, but still getting the errors.

**Here're the instructions:**

Bus 1 is fed by the power grid (ID: Utility) with the rating of Rated kV: 4.16, 3-Phase SR Rating: 500 kVAsc, and 3-Phase X/R: 12.

A heater (ID: HTR 1) with the rating of 50kW and 85% PF (use the calculator of theloading page) is connected to Bus 1. (Hint: heater is a static load).

HTR 1 is protected by the fuse (ID: HTR1_FU): ABB (Manufacturer) & Max kV:4.16 (Use the Library to filter), & Cont. Amp: 8.

Bus 2 is connected to Bus 1 through a cable (ID: CBL 1), a breaker (ID: Bus 2_BKR), and a step-down transformer (XFMR 1).

CBL 1, which is directly connected to Bus 1, is: Freq: 60, Type: CU, kV: 5, #/C: 3, Insul: EPR, Source: KERITE, and Install: Non-Mag (Use the Library), Size: 1/0, Length: 50 ft.

The rating of XFMR 1 connected to the cable is Prim: 4.16 kV, Sec. 0.48 kV, Power Rating: 300 kVA. Use the Typical Z & X/R option at the Impedance page.

Bus 2_BKR, which is feeding Bus 2, is Cutler-Hammer, HMCA, 0.48kV, 800 A (Use the Library at the Rating page). The rating plug of its trip device is 500 Amp.

LT Pickup: 500 Amp & Short-time Pickup: 3500 Amp & St Band: Max (Use the Trip Device page. Deactivate the Ground protection). Keep in mind that each breaker has a Trip Device Unit which acts as the Brain of the breaker.

Update the ID of the bus to Bus 2 if you have not yet done that.

The node between CBL 1 and XFMR 1 has the ID of Node 1.

Bus 2 is feeding a lumped load (ID: LL 1) with the rating of 200 Amp and 85% PF.

Update the Load Type so that it is 50% constant kVA and 50% constant Z.

LL 1 is protected by a breaker (ID: LL 1_BKR): Cutler-Hammer, HMCA, 0.48kV, 800 A (Use the Library at the Rating page). The rating plug of its trip device is 500 Amp. LT Pickup: 500 Amp & Short-time Pickup: 5000 Amp & St Band: Max (Use the Trip Device page. Deactivate the Ground protection).

Comment: XFMR 1 appears to be flipped. Rotate it, correct primary and secondary kV and run again.

Answer (score 1):

> Error 101-01: [Bus 2] Bus base kV is out of 40% range from bus nominal kV. Error 722: [XFMR 1] 2W transformer secondary kV is out of 40% range from bus nominal kV.

Whenever you get this error, you can be sure that you have a voltage mismatch in your system. Meaning your bus rating doesn't match your transformer or your CB rating doesn't match your bus. It's hard to troubleshoot this without the program but I can assure you that you are having a voltage mismatch.

Try opening the devices upwards towards the source to find the issue.